# Pointers, Pointer Arithmetic, and Raw Data in Swift

Tags: swift

My application uses a somewhat complex inmutable data structure that is encoded in a binary file. I need to have access to it at the byte level, avoiding any copying. Normally, I would use C or C++ pointer arithmetic and typecasts, to access and interpret the raw byte values. I would like to do the same with Swift.

I have found that the following works:

```
class RawData {
    var data: NSData!

    init(rawData: NSData) {
      data = rawData
    }

    func read<T>(byteLocation: Int) -> T {
      let bytes = data.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(byteLocation, sizeof(T))).bytes
      return UnsafePointer<T>(bytes).memory
    }

    func example_ReadAnIntAtByteLocation5() -> Int {
      return read(5) as Int
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure how efficient it is. Do `data.subdataWithRange` and `NSMakeRange` allocate objects every time I call them, or are they just syntactic sugar for dealing with pointers?

Is there a better way to do this in Swift?

**EDIT:**

I have created a small Objective-C class that just encapsulates a function to offset a pointer by a given number of bytes:

```
@implementation RawDataOffsetPointer

inline void* offsetPointer(void* ptr, int bytes){
    return (char*)ptr + bytes;
}

@end
```

If I include this class in the bridging header, then I can change my `read` method to

```
func read<T>(byteLocation: Int) -> T {
  let ptr = offsetPointer(data.bytes, CInt(byteLocation))
  return UnsafePointer<T>(ptr).memory
}
```

which will not copy data from my buffer, or allocate other objects.

However, it would still be nice to do some pointer arithmetic from Swift, if it were possible.

Comment: My gut says that if the subdata is immutable, swift wouldn't bother to copy it.

Comment: Just on this point- is there a way in Swift to read a stream of `UInt8`s from an NSData in a completely safe way?  Or from a file even?  I'm using this NSData/subdata dance in a binary file parser dingus I'm writing now, I really hate looking at that "unsafe" nonsense but it seems like the only way I can get the raw bytes out of the file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you just want to do it directly, `UnsafePointer<T>` can be manipulated arithmetically:

```
   let oldPointer = UnsafePointer<()>
   let newPointer = oldPointer + 10
```

You can also cast a pointer like so (`UnsafePointer<()>` is equivalent to `void *`)

```
   let castPointer = UnsafePointer<MyStruct>(oldPointer)
```

Comment: `let oldPointer = UnsafePointer<()>` gives me an error `'>' is not a postfix unary operator`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 15):

I would recommend looking into `NSInputStream`, which allows you to read `NSData` as a series of bytes (`UInt8` in Swift).

Here is a little sample I put together in the playground:

```
func generateRandomData(count:Int) -> NSData
{
    var array = Array<UInt8>(count: count, repeatedValue: 0)

    arc4random_buf(&array, UInt(count))
    return NSData(bytes: array, length: count)
}

let randomData = generateRandomData(256 * 1024)

let stream = NSInputStream(data: randomData)
stream.open() // IMPORTANT

var readBuffer = Array<UInt8>(count: 16 * 1024, repeatedValue: 0)

var totalBytesRead = 0

while (totalBytesRead < randomData.length)
{
    let numberOfBytesRead = stream.read(&readBuffer, maxLength: readBuffer.count)

    // Do something with the data

    totalBytesRead += numberOfBytesRead
}
```

You can create an `extension` to read primitive types like so:

```
extension NSInputStream
{
    func readInt32() -> Int
    {
        var readBuffer = Array<UInt8>(count:sizeof(Int32), repeatedValue: 0)

        var numberOfBytesRead = self.read(&readBuffer, maxLength: readBuffer.count)

        return Int(readBuffer[0]) << 24 |
            Int(readBuffer[1]) << 16 |
            Int(readBuffer[2]) << 8 |
            Int(readBuffer[3])
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend the simple way to use UnsafeArray.

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: filename)
let ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)
let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start:ptr, count:data.length)
```

Comment: When I try this I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when it gets to the bytes line.

Comment: With the current Swift version, the last line should be `let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start:ptr, count:data.length)`